# Catching mouse events on html5 canvas when placed in the background

Tags: html, canvas

I placed the html5 canvas in the background using the following
style="position:fixed;top:0;left:0;z-index:-1;"

On my window.onload(), I am adding a mouse event listener to the canvas as follows
canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', onMouseMove, false)
but unfortunately my canvas is not receiving any mouse events. How do you propagate events down the z-axis? Is it possible to do it without using any external library(if exist)?

I tried searching for it but couldn't found anything relevant so far.

Answer (score 1):

You want to "bubble" a mousemove event from a none-fixed element to a fixed element with different parents? I think you have to check and trigger for your own:

Build a wrapper for the none fixed element(s). This gets also a mousemove event listener. If the mousemove is over the fixed element (check clientX and clientY), trigger the mousemove event on the fixed element.

E.g. tested with firefox:

```
function onCanvasMouseMove(oEvent) {
    console.log(oEvent);
}

// wrapper mousemove handler: 
// if the mouse is over the canvas, trigger mousemove event on it.
function onWrapperMouseMove(oEvent) {
    if (
        oEvent.clientX <= oCanvas.offsetWidth
        && oEvent.clientY <= oCanvas.offsetHeight
    ) {
        oEvent.stopPropagation();
        var oNewEvent = document.createEvent("MouseEvents");
        oNewEvent.initMouseEvent("mousemove", true, true, window, 0, oEvent.screenX, oEvent.screenY, oEvent.clientX, oEvent.clientY, false, false, false, false, 0, null);
        oCanvas.dispatchEvent(oNewEvent);
    }
}

var oCanvas;

window.onload = function() {
    oCanvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
    oCanvas.addEventListener('mousemove', onCanvasMouseMove, false);
    // add mousemove listener to none-fixed wrapper
    var oWrapper = document.getElementById('wrapper');
    oWrapper.addEventListener('mousemove', onWrapperMouseMove, false);
};
```

Also see [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/JUUZE/).

P.s.: bubbling is not the right word, it normaly means bubbling the event to the parent elements.

Comment: Perfect. works on all browsers. My wrapper is body element so I dont require the if() condition inside onWrapperMouseMove. Thanks!

Comment: Consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) as an answer if it solved your problem

Answer (score 0):

You could try setting the overlaid elements to [`pointer-events: none`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/pointer-events) but this will only work in Firefox, Chrome and Safari.  It might also cause you some issues if there are some elements and mouse events you do want to handle before they hit the `canvas`.